# self-complementary graph of $v=8$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Richard J. Trudeau's book "[Introduction to Graph Theory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Graph-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486678709)", in ch 2 there's an exercise:

> Exercises 16. Find a self-complementary graph with $v=8$. 
>   Of the 12,346 graphs with $v=8$ only four are self-complementary.

The answer is given in page 199:

> The names are those of students who found them.
>   [image]

However, I came out with something as:

[image]

- I paint $K_8$ edges as blue and red in Fig (a)
- then detach them in Fig (b)
- so both blue and red part are actually isomorphic to Fig (c)

Looks like I find a self-complementary graph of $v=8$.

The problem is, the one I found, is not isomorphic to any of the 4 graphs given in the answer: it has 4 vertices of degree 5, only the graph by Fanny Zambuto has this feature; but then Fanny's 4 triangles do not share edges while mine do.

So where did I miss?

Comment: MathWorld shows ten self-isomorphic graphs on eight vertices.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-ComplementaryGraph.html

Comment: You meant $v=8$ in the title, right?

Comment: @saulspatz of course, so sorry about the mistake, I must be short just now

Comment: I checked the number of self complementary graphs on $8$ vertices with nauty, and it confirmed that there are $10$.